# Paid to free reflection time Appstore

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, app-store-connect

I have made my applciation status paid to free. But still its showing paid staus in itunes, but it changed as free in itunesconnect.How long it will take to reflect in itunes, or should i want to change anything other settings in rights and pricing .Here the screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Did you update a new version of your app for that or you just changed the price tier of the app from itunesconnect?

Comment: @Manthan i have just changed price tier of the app from itunesconnect

Comment: When did you change the status ? Change is not instantly on the AppStore.

Comment: It will take some time. The change will not effect instantly.

Comment: 24h for setting the app "available" to "removed from the appstore".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple document said:

> Changes you make to app-level information go live immediately (expect
>   24 hours for a full refresh of the change on the App Store)

You can refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html)